# Paypal Website Payments Standard with dynamic Amount

Tags: php, yii, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a scenario where a user can input the amount he wants to be billed. I use buynow buttons that are created using code. Now in this case what what i had in mind was to:

- Set minimum billing amount to 10$

  - If he enters below that, give error.
  - Set the amount of buynow button 10$ when form loads.
- Once User inputs a number greater than 10 do an ajax request to controller

  - Check if their is a button saved in DB against that amount that was created earier on PayPal.
  - If button does not exist, create a new one on PayPal, save button in the DB.
  - Return the HTML of the newly created button
  - Replace the existing button with the returned HTML

Problem with this approach is that it might be too heavy. I also do not want to spread form over 2 pages. Are there any alternate and better options? Can i do some tweaks to make this option more robust?

Answer (score 0):

A better option in this case would be to use the API and do the payments via either Express or Payments Pro. Essentially, you're trying to over-complicate this by making the buttons to the job of the API; getting the worst of both worlds in the process.

You could still utilize a "pay now" button graphic, but just submit your own request to the paypal express gateway (exactly what the button does for you) with a couple curl commands.

There are many tutorials available, but PayPal provides PHP code and a complete walkthrough on their site, so best, in my opinion, to go right to the source.

Log into PayPal -> Merchant Services -> Express Checkout

Under "Setting it up", you'll find all the implementation details.